# I have a lamp to repair vs I have a lamp to be repaired. To infinitive passive or active?

Tags: grammar, to-infinitive

I'm trying to study to infinitive passive/active form, and I've seen [the explanation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ko/%EB%AC%B8%EB%B2%95/%EC%98%81%EA%B5%AD%EC%8B%9D-%EB%AC%B8%EB%B2%95/infinitive-active-or-passive).

It says, we use the active infinitive if we are focusing on the agent(doer of the action), and passive if we are focusing on the receiver of the action(one who experiences it) or when it's not important to mention the agent:
﻿

> The doctor gave me an eye-patch **to wear.** (O)
>
> The doctor gave me an eye-patch **to be worn.** (X) since the 'doer' of the action here is *me*.

But I'm still unclear about when to use passive/active, because I feel like in most cases both forms are acceptable and it's hard to distinguish when should I *not* use one of the two.

For example,

> a) I have a lamp to repair.
>
> b) I have a lamp to be repaired.

My teacher said a) is more accurate here, but I feel like b) is more appropriate according to the explanation since

1) here, it's not important to know who does the repairing.

2) And also, there is no explicit 'doer' in the sentence. I mean, I know some person will repair it but the doer of the action is not specified in the sentence. Then does it mean I can use the active infinitive even when the doer of the action is not explicit in the sentence?

Also, this is from TV series, Friends:

> A: "What are you doing with the lamp?"
>
> B: "I'm just taking it to **get rewired**."

Can I rephrase B's comments to "I'm taking it to **rewire**." (for the same reason as the example sentence above) and is it acceptable?

If one is more natural usage than the other, why is that?

Comment: To me, at least, while both phrasings are grammatically correct, the active in your second and third examples implies that the subject (I) is the one that will be performing the action, whereas the passive doesn't specify.

Comment: @AmaiKotori Thanks, so in most cases both active and passive are acceptable but in the first example (eye patch to be worn) passive is wrong? But how would I know when both forms are okay and when they aren't? complicated,,

Comment: Grammatically speaking, the passive in the first isn't really incorrect either; it's just contextually incorrect because there's only one interpretation that makes sense, and that interpretation supports the active.  Eh, put differently, the important part of the first example is that *you* wear the eye patch, not that the eye patch is worn in general.  If the doctor were instead, say, giving you an experimental eye patch design for testing, and it didn't matter who wore it, the passive there would be a bit awkward but not incorrect.